# Unable to send data over TCP from java socket to .net tcp server

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, client

i am trying to get an android app to send tcp data to a server on my network. The server was written in c#.

When i use the code below to transmit data, the server only receives a whole series of \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0.

Does anyone know why?

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
pw.print("test");
socket.close();
```

Comment: One thought is to check if the encoding of what is being sent matches what the server expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but you might want to try manually flushing the `PrintWriter`. You did pass `true` to its constructor to request autoflushing, but I believe this only occurs when you print a newline character, which your sample code doesn't do.

Comment: shouldn't the `close` flush before closing?

Comment: Yes, but that will only flush the socket's buffers. The `PrintWriter` class maintains buffers of its own which must be flushed before the socket is closed to ensure that all data is delivered properly.

Answer (score 1):

Close the PrintWriter, not the Socket.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try println("test").  In java you need to flush the line, so that may be the cause of your issues.